# Searchable dropdown value is not working in laravel 8

Tags: jquery, laravel-8, php-7.4

I'm attempting to make an Organisation dropdown list from DB value with a searchable option select2. For this one, i use form select and my searchable function not working. No error,just not working. I try to import the select2 script but still nothing happen. I wonder where it all goes wrong.

Here is my view blade.

```
<div class="form-group row">
{!! Form::Label('organisation_id', 'Organisasi') !!}
 {!! Form::select('organisation_id', $organisation, 1, ['class' => 'select2 form-control ','name'=>'organisation']) !!}
 @if ($errors->has('organisation_id'))
 <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('organisation_id') }}</span>
   @endif
</div>

<script>
$(organisation).ready(function() {
$('.select2').select2();
});

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</script>
```

Comment: Is jQuery present on your page? If not, you'll need to add it if you wish to write your JS like that.

Comment: yes, i already imported it

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us what the outputted `<select><option...</select>` code looks like please?

Comment: `$(organisation).ready` looks like a typo.  https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#single-select-boxes

Comment: @H2ONOCK i don't have an option select because my value is retrieved from DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED !

First I imported my CDN jquery:

CSS/Stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css">
```

Script :

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

For my view Blade just change to this

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 console.log('');
 $('.select2').select2();
 });
</script>
```

Works very well

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change your jQuery code to be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select2').select2();
});
```

This will initialise your select2 plugin on any element that has a class of 'select2' on it.

Comment: it's still not working, i wonder which jQuery that i need to import